# Cyclic spectrum equality to spectral correlation density

Tags: demodulation, derivation, cyclostationary-random-process

As long as I know, the cyclic auto-correlation is defined as:

$$R_x^\alpha\left(\tau\right)=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\Delta  t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}x\left(t-\frac{\tau}{2}\right)x^*\left(t+\frac{\tau}{2}\right)e^{-2\pi j\alpha t}dt$$

and the cyclic spectrum is defined as:
$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R_x^\alpha\left(\tau\right)e^{-2\pi j f \tau}d\tau$$

Now, the cyclic spectrum is also equivalent to the spectral correlation function which is defined as:
$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, f + \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)X_{1 / \Delta f}^*\left(t, f - \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)dt$$

where $X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, \nu\right)$ is the complex envelope of the narrow-band-pass of $x(t)$ with a center frequency of $\nu$ and approximate bandwidth of $\Delta f$ is defined as:

$$X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, \nu\right)=\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}x(u)e^{-2\pi j \nu u}du$$

I have seen those relations in numerous places but I could not find a reference showing the derivation of equivalence between the definition of the cyclic spectrum and the spectral correlation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The spectral correlation function is defined as:
$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, f + \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)X_{1 / \Delta f}^*\left(t, f - \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)dt$$

Substitution of the definition:
$$X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, \nu\right)=\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}x(u)e^{-2\pi j \nu u}du$$
leads to
$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f \int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}x(u)e^{-2\pi j \left(f + \frac{\alpha}{2}\right) u}du\ \int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}x(v)e^{-2\pi j \left(f - \frac{\alpha}{2}\right) v}dv\ dt$$

A little rearranging:

$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f \int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}x(u)x(v)e^{-2\pi j \left(f(u-v) + \frac{\alpha}{2}(u+v)\right)}dudvdt$$

Define $\tau=u-v$

$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f \int_{t-\frac{1}{\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{\Delta f}}\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}R_x(u, \tau)e^{-2\pi j \left(f\tau + \alpha(u-\frac{\tau}{2})\right)}dud\tau dt$$

Define $z=u-\frac{\tau}{2}$

$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f \int_{t-\frac{1}{\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{\Delta f}}\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}R_x(z, \tau)e^{-2\pi j \left(f\tau + \alpha z\right)}dzd\tau dt$$

Now, $\Delta t$ is not a parameter in the function anymore. This leads to

$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\Delta f \int_{t-\frac{1}{\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{\Delta f}}\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}R_x(z, \tau)e^{-2\pi j \left(f\tau + \alpha z\right)}dzd\tau$$

Integration leads to

$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R_x^\alpha(\tau)e^{-2\pi j f \tau}d\tau$$

which looks like complete proof but probably there are some inaccuracies in the middle of the process...

My reference is Gardner, William. "Measurement of spectral correlation." IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing 34.5 (1986): 1111-1123.

Comment: Gideon, if this resolves your question, please select it as the answer (give it the check mark).

Comment: @PeterK., I do not feel comfortable accepting my own answer to my own question without an external review. Therefore, I did not mark my answer as the accepted one. Do you think that the derivation is satisfactory?